# INSERT * query - field order danger?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm adding records to a table from the same table in a separate database file:

```
INSERT INTO P
SELECT *
FROM P IN 'C:\update.accdb'
```

Can I trust that Access is matching fields by *Name* or by *field order*? If someone re-orders the fields of P in C:\update.accdb, will that corrupt the mapping?

Comment: Why don't you specify the column names, then you'll know exactly what is being inserted and in what order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database is matching names by *field order*, not by name.

Always use a column list.

The SQL standard and every other database uses positions.  MS Access does the same thing, because there is no requirement that the fields be named in the `select` clause.  So, there is no necessarily any information for aligning names.

Comment: But I can save some keystrokes by excluding the column names and all it will cost me is MASSIVE UNDETECTABLE DATA CORRUPTION? ;-) Ugh, I have some queries to modify.

Comment: @pteranodon . . . Oh, often it is detectable.  You get some really strange error on some row that is rather hard to debug.

Comment: I would notice if a date field received text due to data validation errors at the insert, but two number fields switching would lead to a silent mis-mapping. Yipes! Always use a column list. Always use a column list.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff has already said this, but just for emphasis:

## Always use a column list, in every database, in every query.

Your coworkers, clients, and generally descendants unto the nth generation will thank you.

So your query should be:

```
insert into something (columns...)
select columns...
from somewhere
```